# How do I make use of NDT results to fix a network timeout issues?

Tags: internet-connection, adsl, timeout, adsl-router

I've been experiencing a significant slow down of my home internet connection. ISP sent over some engineers and they didn't think there was an issue with the setup or the connection. All they did was a ping google.com -t test and the ping ran without any timeouts.

Since my pages keep timing out, I ran the NDT test from http://www.measurementlab.net/run-ndt.
Here's what I got:

---

Your system: Windows 7 version 6.1
Java version: 1.6.0_27 (x86)

TCP receive window: 114176 current, 135936 maximum
0.001331558 packets lost during test
Round trip time: 285 msec (minimum), 1193 msec (maximum), 712.7 msec (average)
Jitter: 908 msec
0 seconds spend waiting following a timeout
TCP time-out counter: 816
140 selective acknowledgement packets received

No duplex mismatch condition was detected.
The test did not detect a cable fault.
No network congestion was detected.
No network addess translation appliance was detected.

0.5014% of the time was not spent in a receiver limited or sender limited state.
45.839999999999996% of the time the connection is limited by the client machine's receive buffer.
Optimal receive buffer: 139198464 bytes
Bottleneck link: Cable/DSL modem
0 duplicate ACKs set

---

So, is there an issue with my machine's/router's "receive buffer"? (WTH is a that anyway?) :)
Anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: What is the geographical distance between you and the ndt server?  None of these results indicate a problem as is, but the average round trip is 700ms or .7 seconds, which is pretty slow.  It suggests you are distant from the server.

Comment: Approx 3300km (from distance-calculator.co.uk).

Comment: Still a pretty high ping for that distance.  Could you get a copy of http://winmtr.net/ and test against the IP address given in NDT, it will tell us where in the path the delay is.

Comment: I will give this a try. One of my biggest concerns is that, I'm seeing serious problems when connecting to HTTPs sites. Worst affected are services like GMail, GDocs. I was wondering whether there was something fishy going on at the ISP. But, I've found no evidence of traffic shaping or anything else.

Comment: Here's WinMtr Data: http://pastebin.com/9Yk2d9fV

Comment: I am not sure if you are going to get anything definitive here, but at least one packet was 600ms at the first few hops, which could indicate a local problem.  It was averaged down to 73 which meant the majority of packets made it through ok.  I would run this a few times against a few destinations and see if a pattern emerges.

Comment: Is there any reason to believe that the local problem could be the router? It's pretty old now. Since the ISP's technology hasn't change, I don't see how an aging router could cause a problem. I have tested several machines on the same network. All have this regular slow down issue.